# Determine the continuity of the given function

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

The function is $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x) = x$ if $x$ is rational and $f(x)=1-x$ if $x$ is irrational.

I don´t know if my proof is 100% correct or if I could omit the last part (I think I can´t), so I would appreciate some feedback. My proof goes as follows.

Suppose that $a \in \mathbb{Q}$. By the density of the rationals and irrationals in $\mathbb{R}$ there exist sequences, say $(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, $(y_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of rational and irrational numbers respectively, both of which converge to $a$. But then $f(x_{n}) = (x_{n}) \to a$ and $f(y_{n})= (1-y_{n}) \to 1-a$. Thus,  $f$ is continuous at $a$ if and only if $1-a=f(a)=a$, if and only if $a = 1/2$.

Now suppose that $a$ is irrational. Then $f$ is not continuos at $a$, for, there is a sequence, say $(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ of rational numbers, such that $x_{n} \to a$, but $f(x_{n}) = x_{n} \to a \neq 1-a = f(a)$.

Finally, let $(x_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of real numbers that converges to 1/2. Let $A$ be the set of positive integers $n$ such that $x_{n} \in \mathbb{Q}$, and let $B$ be the set of positive integers $n$ such that $x_{n} \notin \mathbb{Q}$.

If $A$ contains infinitely many elements, but $B$ finitely many, there is an integer $N$, such that for all $n\geq N$ we have $f(x_{n}) = x_{n} \to 1/2 = f(1/2).$

If $A$ contains finitely many elements, but $B$ finitely many, then there is an integer $N$ such that, for all $n \geq N$ we have $f(x_{n}) = 1-x_{n} \to 1-(1/2) = 1/2 = f(1/2)$.

If both $A$ and $B$ contain infinitely many elements, there exist subsequences $(x_{n_{k}})_{n_{k}\in\mathbb{N}}$ of rational numbers, and $(x_{n_{l}})_{n_{l}}\in\mathbb{N}$ of irrational numbers, both of them converging to 1/2 (because the mother sequence converges to 1/2) such that

$$f(x_{n_{k}}) = x_{n_{k}} \to \frac{1}{2}$$ and

$$f(x_{n_{l}}) = 1-x_{n_{l}} \to \frac{1}{2}.$$

Thus $f$ is continuous at 1/2 and discontinuous at every other point in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Proof of what? You have just defined a function, not said anything that needs proved.

Comment: If you dropped the unnecessary assumption at the start that $a \in \Bbb Q$, and just let $a$ be any real number, then your first paragraph is sufficient. You never made any use of this assumption of $a$ being rational.